# my main.css file will not link using jinja/flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Im new to using Flask/Jinja but I think that I have my syntax correct yet my css file will not link/modify my app page.

my css file sits in the path:

```
program/src/static/css/main.css
```

In my base.html file I tried to link the main.css file using the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static, filename='css/main.css') }}"/>
```

I should note that Im utilizing bootstrap css (which is working) which is linked above the link to my file in the base.html.

Currently trying to use the css file to alter a linked page written using the jinja format

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

yet when I run the page none of my CSS code that I write links to the app page when it runs.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the snippet is your actual code, then you might want to close that string,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static, filename='css/main.css') }}"/>
                                               ^
```

Comment: Sorry - the string is closed in my code, missed it when I copied over to ask the question

Comment: Then are you sure the file path is correct? Is your program/src/static folder recognized as _the_ static folder?

Comment: thank you DarthCadeus - didnt realize that I needed to designate the static folder in app=Flask(__name__,static_url_path='path...')